# Make the option available if i click the remove button

Tags: jquery

I am facing the problem that if I click on "remove" my selectbox should disappear as well as my option that I have selected in the select box should be available in next select box again. Right now if I click on remove it is disappearing but the option doesn't seems to be available in other select fields.

```js
var uniqId = 1;
        var selectedOptionDataList = new Array();
        var jsonData = [
          {'name': 'A', 'value': 'A'},
            {'name': 'B', 'value': 'B'},
            {'name': 'C', 'value': 'C'},
            {'name': 'D', 'value': 'D'}
            
        ];

        function regenerateSelectbox(){
          $('select.dyn-select').each(function(){
              var _selector = $(this);
                var _curVal = _selector.val();
                
                _selector.html(generateOption());
                if(_curVal == ""){
                  _selector.append('<option value="'+ _curVal +'">select</option>');
                }else{
                  _selector.append('<option value="'+ _curVal +'">'+ _curVal +'</option>');
                }
                _selector.val(_curVal);
            })
        }

        function checkOptionExistences(listOptionVal){
          var _found = false;
            
          $.each(selectedOptionDataList, function(inn, vnn){ 
               if(vnn.selectboxoption == listOptionVal){
                 _found = true;
                }
            });
            
            return _found;
        }

        function generateOption(){
          var optionArr = new Array();
            optionArr.push('<option value="">select</option>');
            
          $.each(jsonData, function(i, v){
              if(!checkOptionExistences(v.value)){
               optionArr.push('<option value="'+ v.value +'">'+ v.name +'</option>');
                }
            });
            
            return optionArr.join('\n');
        }

        function removeSelectedOptionFromList(param){
          var tmpArrList = selectedOptionDataList;
            selectedOptionDataList = new Array();
            
            $.each(tmpArrList, function(i, v){
              if(param.selectboxid != v.selectboxid){
                  selectedOptionDataList.push({'selectboxid':v.selectboxid, 'selectboxoption':v.selectboxoption});
                }
            });
        }

        function selectedOptionList(param){
          var _found = false;
          $.each(selectedOptionDataList, function(i, v){
              if(param.selectboxid == v.selectboxid){
                  _found = true;
                  v.selectboxoption = param.selectboxoption;
                }
            });
            
            if(!_found){
            selectedOptionDataList.push({'selectboxid':param.selectboxid, 'selectboxoption':param.selectboxoption});
            }
        }

        $('#btn-create').click(function(){
          if(selectedOptionDataList.length == jsonData.length){
              alert('No data available');
            }else{
           $('div#selectField-wrapper').append('<div><a class="remove_field">remove</a><select class="dyn-select" id="select-'+ uniqId +'">'+ generateOption() +'</select><div><br>');
             uniqId++;
            }
        });

        $(document).on('change', 'select.dyn-select', function(){
          var _selector = $(this);
          if(_selector.val() == ""){
              removeSelectedOptionFromList({'selectboxid':_selector.attr('id')});
            }else{
              selectedOptionList({'selectboxid':_selector.attr('id'), 'selectboxoption':_selector.val()});
            }
            
            regenerateSelectbox();
        });
        
        $('#dropdown-wrapper').on('click', ".remove_field", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-wrapper" class="row">

   <div class="col-md-3" id='selectField-wrapper'>
   </div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show more of your `html` snippet? (Kindly update your question)

Comment: my html code relevant to this  piece of code is this much only